# Some auto-generated controls missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My app today started throwing the following error:

```
The name 'Control' does not exist in the current context
```

It's happening only in 2 controls in the page, even if I rename them. If I add the control declaration myself in the `.designer.cs` file it works but when rebuilt it throws the error again.

Any ideas what might be wrong? I can paste all the code but I feel there's just too much to paste, but if you want me to post some of the code just tell me.

Comment: try deleting you designer file and recreate it, this is a common issue   caused by the designer file

Comment: how do I recreate it? Building it is not creating the designer.

Comment: Delete the designer file then right click on the aspx file and click Convert to Web Application

Comment: That did it, thanks. If you want post it as an Answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designer file for an aspx sometimes does no correctly write code for controls. so in such a case delete the designer file then right click on you .aspx file and Click "Convert to Web Application" this action regenerates the designer file again correctly

Answer (score 0):

You should check the code behind the filename and inherits property on @Page directive and ensure that they both match....

You should also be sure to exclude other page which is referncing to same code behind file...